# Statistics on hotlinked images

Tags: web-server, analysis

Is there a web statistics application that can tell me how many people are hotlinking (or embedding) an image? Google Analytics can't since it needs to render HTML to gather information, so any hotlinked image will not be counted.  In other words I need a http based web analytics application (web based is preferred).

Comment: So, in other words, you want to know how many (or which) sites are loading images direct from your site?

Comment: Yep

Comment: The phrase is "direct linking", not hardlinking.

Comment: ahh no... its not hardlinking its hotlinking :P or embedded...

Comment: Is you site hosted or on your own server?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got access logs that contain referrer information, you can just look for hits to those images that have a referrer that isn't your site.

Comment: Bill beat me back to it :)

Comment: :(, I wanted something more user friendly

Comment: So write something and make it friendly? :)  Or, hire someone to hack something together for you that's friendly.  I'm sure you could find someone on this site, even *cough* :)

Comment: Or, you could ask on SF for a solution... oh... wait... nvm

Comment: I think that something like this is going to be highly site-specific.  On previous looks for a program to do it, I haven't found anything, and have ended up going with grep to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to install stuff on the machine, [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) can give you what you need. You can either install it on the live server and have it run under CGI, regularly parsing the log files, or, grab the log files into your local machine and just run it there.

What you're looking for are referrers linking to static files, like JPG, PNG and GIF files. You can set up awstats to only index these extensions, and then any referrers it finds are people hotlinking your files.

Comment: Good answer.  I hadn't though of using it like that.